# PHP - How do I access values of a mysql_fetch_assoc with a variable?

Tags: c#, php, mysql, unity-game-engine

I'll try to keep it short, since I'm probably missing something very simple here.

Essentially, what I have is a for loop in c# that runs 25 instances of PHP code, each time passing in a different string as the "roomID" value:

```
<?php
    $servername = "server";
    $username = $_REQUEST["username"];
    $roomID = $_REQUEST["roomID"];
    $dbName = "dbName";
    $user = "user";
    $pass = "pass";

    $conn = mysql_connect($servername, $user, $pass);
    mysql_select_db($dbName);

    $SQL = "SELECT '" . $roomID . "' FROM dbName WHERE Username = '" . $username ."'";
    $Result = mysql_query($SQL) or die("DB Error");
    $data = mysql_fetch_assoc($Result) or die("DB Error");
    echo $data[$roomID];

    mysql_close();
?>
```

At the end, I want to get the value from $data[$roomID] (for a more static example: $data['Password']), but the problem is... this is what it returns:

```
Room1
Room2
Room3
Room4
Room5
Room5
```

And so on, when it should (based on database defaults) return:

```
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
```

I'm completely stumped on how to solve this. I've tried switching to mysql_fetch_array and using the index 0, but that also returns the variable name rather than the value. I'm also completely new to both PHP and MySQL, so I'm not too knowledgable about things. For all I know, I could be missing something simple.

Comment: If you're passing the `roomId` in from the request as the actual id, then your SQL query becomes `select 4 from table where username = ...`. Is that your desired result? Otherwise change it to `select <cols> from  table where username ="..." and roomid = "<roomid>"`. Also, that code is prone to sql injection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is where your problem resides.

```
$SQL = "SELECT '" . $roomID . "' FROM dbName WHERE Username = '" . $username ."'";
```

You are using single quote **'** to define column, you must use **`** the one next to tilde. like

```
$SQL = "SELECT `" . $roomID . "` FROM dbName WHERE Username = '" . $username ."'";
```

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly it.